# Foreign keys in mongo?

Tags: sql, mongodb, foreign-keys, nosql

[image]

How do I design a scheme such this in MongoDB? I think there are no foreign keys!

Comment: You're thinking relationally, instead of document-oriented. :P

Comment: Why are you using MongoDB if you want a relational database?

Comment: :D I'm trying to understand document-oriented method; How can I solve this task?

Comment: If you want the answer to the document oriented way of thinking see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18637581/80428. The current accepted answer works but is shoehorning relational database to a document store which is not what NoSQL is about.

Comment: @Pat I don't see how "document-oriented" way of thinking substitutes relationships. Relationships are a key part of database management systems

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You may be interested in using a ORM like Mongoid or MongoMapper.

http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/referenced/1-n.html

In a NoSQL database like MongoDB there are not 'tables' but collections. Documents are grouped inside Collections. You can have any kind of document – with any kind of data – in a single collection. Basically, in a NoSQL database it is up to you to decide how to organise the data and its relations, if there are any.

What Mongoid and MongoMapper do is to provide you with convenient methods to set up relations quite easily. Check out the link I gave you and ask any thing.

Edit:

In mongoid you will write your scheme like this:

```
class Student
  include Mongoid::Document

    field :name
    embeds_many :addresses
    embeds_many :scores    
end

class Address
  include Mongoid::Document

    field :address
    field :city
    field :state
    field :postalCode
    embedded_in :student
end

class Score
  include Mongoid::Document

    belongs_to :course
    field :grade, type: Float
    embedded_in :student
end


class Course
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  has_many :scores  
end
```

Edit:

```
> db.foo.insert({group:"phones"})
> db.foo.find()                  
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4df6539ae90592692ccc9940"), "group" : "phones" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4df6540fe90592692ccc9941"), "group" : "phones" }
>db.foo.find({'_id':ObjectId("4df6539ae90592692ccc9940")}) 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4df6539ae90592692ccc9940"), "group" : "phones" }
```

You can use that ObjectId in order to do relations between documents.

Comment: There are document with items, and I wanna to bind cities. I've create collection with cities, but I don't know how to bind cities with items. PS sorry for my bad english.

Comment: UPD. I'am using PHP as a programming language, how can I use mongoid, if it is written in Ruby?

Comment: @Жирайр Казаросян: Oh I see :) Being a Ruby developer makes me think only in Ruby :)  I am afraid that I do not have experience with PHP and Mongo, but you can check this link: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Libraries%2C+Frameworks%2C+and+Tools

Comment: I've already installed extension, now I'm trying to create document from shell: there are collection with cities, now I'am creating collection with items - db.items.insert({group:"phones", price:3500, city: ?}), but I don't know how to bind city by id...

Comment: Offtopic: can you recomend me some manual/tutorial about Ruby or Ruby On Rails?

Comment: @Жирайр Казаросян: I learned Ruby on Rails with the book Web development with Ruby on Rails, by the pragmatic programmers. You can also get an introduction for free with this screencast http://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies

Comment: For later readers, the "tables" are "collections" in MongoDB. Rows are Documents, and Columns are Fields... Just in case you get mixed up.

Answer (score 79):

> How to design table like this in mongodb?

First, to clarify some naming conventions. MongoDB uses `collections` instead of `tables`.

> I think there are no foreign keys!

Take the following model:

```
student
{ 
  _id: ObjectId(...),
  name: 'Jane',
  courses: [
    { course: 'bio101', mark: 85 },
    { course: 'chem101', mark: 89 }
  ]
}

course
{
  _id: 'bio101',
  name: 'Biology 101',
  description: 'Introduction to biology'
}
```

Clearly Jane's course list points to some specific courses. The database does not apply any constraints to the system (*i.e.: foreign key constraints*), so there are no "cascading deletes" or "cascading updates". However, the database does contain the correct information.

In addition, MongoDB has a [DBRef standard](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References) that helps standardize the creation of these references. In fact, if you take a look at that link, it has a similar example.

> How can I solve this task?

To be clear, MongoDB is not relational. There is no standard "normal form". You should model your database appropriate to the data you store and the queries you intend to run.

Comment: Ok, but how can I get cource name data from student collection? db.student.find() will return something like courses: [ { course: 'bio101', mark: 85 } ]

Comment: @Жирайр Казаросян:

> db.foo.find({'_id':ObjectId("4df6539ae90592692ccc9940")})  ------------->

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4df6539ae90592692ccc9940"), "group" : "phones" }

Comment: From mongo doc about DBREF: "Unless you have a compelling reason to use DBRefs, use manual references instead."

Answer (score 39):

We can define the so-called `foreign key` in MongoDB. However, we need to maintain the data integrity ***BY OURSELVES***. For example,

```
student
{ 
  _id: ObjectId(...),
  name: 'Jane',
  courses: ['bio101', 'bio102']   // <= ids of the courses
}

course
{
  _id: 'bio101',
  name: 'Biology 101',
  description: 'Introduction to biology'
}
```

The `courses` field contains `_id`s of courses. **It is easy to define a one-to-many relationship. However, if we want to retrieve the course names of student `Jane`, we need to perform another operation to retrieve the `course` document via `_id`.**

If the course `bio101` is removed, we need to perform another operation to update the `courses` field in the `student` document.

### More: MongoDB Schema Design

The document-typed nature of MongoDB supports flexible ways to define relationships. To define a one-to-many relationship:

#### Embedded document

1. Suitable for one-to-few.
2. Advantage: no need to perform additional queries to another document.
3. Disadvantage: cannot manage the entity of embedded documents individually.

Example:

```
student
{
  name: 'Kate Monster',
  addresses : [
     { street: '123 Sesame St', city: 'Anytown', cc: 'USA' },
     { street: '123 Avenue Q', city: 'New York', cc: 'USA' }
  ]
}
```

#### Child referencing

Like the `student`/`course` example above.

#### Parent referencing

Suitable for one-to-squillions, such as log messages.

```
host
{
    _id : ObjectID('AAAB'),
    name : 'goofy.example.com',
    ipaddr : '127.66.66.66'
}

logmsg
{
    time : ISODate("2014-03-28T09:42:41.382Z"),
    message : 'cpu is on fire!',
    host: ObjectID('AAAB')       // Reference to the Host document
}
```

Virtually, a `host` is the parent of a `logmsg`. Referencing to the `host` id saves much space given that the log messages are squillions.

References:

1. [6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design: Part 1](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)
2. [6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design: Part 2](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2)
3. [6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design: Part 3](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3)
4. [Model One-to-Many Relationships with Document References](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)

Comment: keeping FK constraint enforced manually is not as easy. think about the concurrent updates.

Answer (score 24):

From [The Little MongoDB Book](http://openmymind.net/2011/3/28/The-Little-MongoDB-Book/)

> Yet another alternative to using joins is to denormalize your data. Historically, denormalization was reserved for
>   performance-sensitive code, or when data should be snapshotted (like in an audit log). However, with the ever-
>   growing popularity of NoSQL, many of which don’t have joins, denormalization as part of normal modeling is becoming
>   increasingly common. This doesn’t mean you should duplicate every piece of information in every document. However,
>   rather than letting fear of duplicate data drive your design decisions, consider modeling your data based on what
>   information belongs to what document.

So,

```
student
{ 
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    name: 'Jane',
    courses: [
    { 
        name: 'Biology 101', 
        mark: 85, 
        id:bio101 
    },
  ]
}
```

If its a RESTful API data, replace the course id with a GET link to the course resource

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. Unless you're storing relational data in mongo, in which case, you really should have questioned _why_ you're using mongo.

Comment: Hmm, the existence of duplication or references is not exactly a property of relational databases. It is a property of reality. I guess ACID *is* perhaps a property of relational database that is being assumed here.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:
You should to use "weak references" between collections, using ObjectId properties:

> References store the relationships between data by including links or
> references from one document to another. Applications can resolve
> these references to access the related data. Broadly, these are
> normalized data models.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/#references

This will of course not check any referential integrity. You need to handle "dead links" on your side (application level).

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of ForeignKey is to prevent the creation of data if the field value does not match its ForeignKey. To accomplish this in MongoDB, we use Schema middlewares that ensure the data consistency.

Please have a look at the documentation.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why you cannot use a NOSQL db as a relational DB since you have aggregate pipelines which you can use to create views like SQL inner joins.

Each collection should contain one type e.g. order and order-details is a 1:M relation.

ORDER COLLECTION
id (PK) Type: GUID
OrderNo (candidate or alternate PK)
OrderDate
Customerid (FK)
...more order fields

ORDER-DETAILS COLLECTION
id (PK)
Orderid (FK)
Productid (FK)
Qty
...more fields

PRODUCT
id (PK)
Supplierid (FK)
Name
Cost

And so on.

The reason why you would not simply use a relational database is because a NOSQL database has other features you could use in tandem with relationally designed data collections.

The way you implement the relations is the same as in relational databases. You have to add the foreign keys yourself (primary keys are added automatically for each document object) and create the normalized join collections. A database will not normalize itself usually.

The only caveat is that you have to code referential  integrity yourself as NOSQL does not do that (yet). So in your admin UI if a user tries to delete a parent that has children you throw a friendly error saying they have to delete the children first. It is not hard but you still need to be careful when using DB utilities not to delete a parent that has children because the DB will let you.

Always use the naming conventions for foreign keys id. For example:

ORDER-DETAIL COLLECTION
id (PK)
Orderid (FK) .... you an easily deduce that this foreign key is the primary key in the Order collection by sticking to this naming convention.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @RandallShanePhD Thank you for teaching us how the Ask Question button functions, Mr. PhD.