# Laravel / MongoDB - Foreign key migrations

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I use the jenssegers package to use MongoDB with Laravel, and I would like to know how to make foreign keys, I didn't find anything about it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: you need to read this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334048/foreign-keys-in-mongo, and you don't need to use migrations to create empty tables as there is no concept of tables in nosql, only collections so just create class and push data using Jenssegers use Jenssegers doc for more knowledge

Comment: https://www.larablocks.com/package/jenssegers/mongodb